# Creating drop-down list next to each cell

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a table where in a column D:D frequency of values in a column B:B are calculated. 
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
Is it possible to create drop-down list of values from column A:A next to each cell in column D:D?
For instance I see frequency of 4, click on a drop-down list in the next cell and it gives me all names from A:A that have the same value in a column B:B

Hope that was clear!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it possible , use Data Validation !

Sorry is in PT-BR my Excel ,

[image: Here is the first step]

Here what u gonna have
[image: List ready]

Comment: I know it's data validation but it needs to be conditional. I need to see exact values that correspond to frequency number